# One line python code to return all sublists of list containing specific substring in a particluar column

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, filter, nested-lists

I want to return all the sublists of lists which contains specific substring in a particular column:

For eg:

```
List=[["2006ab","2005ac"],["2005ab","2004ac"],["2006ab","2005ac"],["2006ab","2003ac"],["2006ab","2005ac"]]
```

Search Criteria : Return all sublists which contains substring 2005 at the 2nd index .

Output :

```
[["2006ab","2005ac"],["2006ab","2005ac"],["2006ab","2005ac"]]
```

I tried using :

```
  matching = [s for s in List if "2005" in s[1]]
```

but it returns:

```
[["2006ab","2005ac"],["2005ab","2004ac"],["2006ab","2005ac"],["2006ab","2005ac"]]
```

Comment: yes but 2005 could be at 0 th index of sublist as well, bt my intention is to return all sublists only if it contains 2005 at 1st index of sublists.

Comment: Run it again. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Your code gives the correct result. `[s for s in List if "2005" in s[1]]` gives `[['2006ab', '2005ac'], ['2006ab', '2005ac'], ['2006ab', '2005ac']]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension approach is good and gives the correct result. Are you sure your code is the same from which you pasted the output because it works for me:

```
>>> List=[["2006ab","2005ac"],["2005ab","2004ac"],["2006ab","2005ac"],["2006ab","2003ac"],["2006ab","2005ac"]]
>>> [sublist for sublist in List if '2005' in sublist[1]]
[['2006ab', '2005ac'], ['2006ab', '2005ac'], ['2006ab', '2005ac']]
```

which is same as what you desire.

If you are looking for an alternative, you may use `filter()`

```
>>> filter(lambda x: '2005' in x[1], List)
[['2006ab', '2005ac'], ['2006ab', '2005ac'], ['2006ab', '2005ac']]
```

Comment: Isn't that the same code as his, just replacing `s` with `sublist`?

Comment: This is no different than the OP's code other than renaming `s` to `sublist`.  What's the point of your answer?

Comment: Updated the answer. As question was not properly formatted, I missed the last part

Comment: isn't all of you are posting same code which i actually used?

Comment: If you need filter+lambda, a list comprehension is more idiomatic. I think you misunderstand `filter`. The function argument only need to return true or false: `lambda x: '2005' in x[1]`.  No reason for the ternary expression.

Comment: @NikitaGupta: Your question was not properly formatted, that's why I missed your implementation. Further updated my answer.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Thanks for correcting me. And yes, my understanding of `filter()` was wrong till date :)

Comment: Yes, my code is right. Thanks @anonymous for alternative method.